# Autofac - How To Register This Architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, autofac, ioc-container

In my business layer. I want to make an abstract class and implement by all my entity manager classes.

- *Core*

**IDataAccess.cs**

```
public interface IDataAccess<T>
```

- *Data Access Layer*

**IDepartmentDAL.cs**

```
public interface IDepartmentDAL : IDataAccess<DPT_DEPARTMENT>
```

**EntityFrameworkEntityRepositoryBase.cs**

```
public class EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext> : IDataAccess<TEntity>
```

**EntityFrameworkDepartmentDAL.cs**

```
public class EfDepartmentDAL : EfEntityRepositoryBase<DPT_DEPARTMENT, Context>, IDepartmentDAL
```

- *Business Logic Layer*

**ServiceBase.cs**

```
public abstract class ServiceBase<T> : IDataAccess<T> 
{
    public IDataAccess<T> _dataAccess;
    public ServiceBase(IDataAccess<T> dataAccess)
    {
            _dataAccess = dataAccess;
    }
}
```

**DeparmentManager.cs**

```
public class DepartmentManager : ServiceBase<Department>
{
    public DepartmentManager(IDataAccess<Department> dataAccess) : base(dataAccess)
    {
    }
}
```

- *MVC UI*

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private BaseService<Department> _departmentService;

    public HomeController(BaseService<Department> departmentService)
    {
        _departmentService = departmentService;
    }
}
```

So, how should I register my types to autofac container. I tried many of other topics on my configuration class and could not find any solution. If it is necessary *I can remove second generic (TContext) of EfRepositoryBase class.*

Thanks...

Comment: You may have trouble getting an answer to your question because it verges close to "please write my app for me." I recognize you're having a challenge, but it might be good to expand on what you've done and why what you've tried isn't working. That way people can focus on getting you a working answer instead of possibly giving you something you've already tried.

Comment: Also looks like this may overlap a bit with a second question you asked: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49508546/8116